# About FullRowSelected Properties

Tags: c#

Datagridview's FullRowSelect feature does not work after this code works. Single cell is being selected.

```
private void CaO() 
{
    System.Data.DataTable tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();

    new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sayfa1$]", 
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\ikinciexcel.xlsx; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'").Fill(tbl);
    System.Data.DataTable dtCloned = tbl.Clone();
    dtCloned.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(float);
    foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
    {
        dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
    }
    var f = new Form();
    var dgv = new DataGridView { DataSource = dtCloned, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    dtCloned.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CaO >= 1 and CaO <= 11";
    dataGridView2.Controls.Add(dgv);           
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a C# question, not a C question.  Please edit your tags.

Comment: Erkan Kesemen, add the correct language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `SelectionMode` property

```
var dgv = new DataGridView { 
    DataSource = dtCloned, 
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
};
```

Comment: The FullRowSelect property worked. Now I can't select all datagridview with code ` dataGridView2.SelectAll();

Answer (score 0):

as you said only `Single cell` is being `selected`. from `Datagridview`

firstly set `Datagridview` selection property `multiselect`  to `true`

you can also do that by `code` like this

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = True;
```

then you can simply select all `Datagridview` like

```
private void selectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.SelectAll();
}
```